# How to configure a DNS server by YAST2

Tags: dns, opensuse, bind, suse, yast

I run these commands to install DNS server dependencies on openSUSE Tumbleweed:

```
sudo zypper in -t pattern dhcp_dns_server
sudo systemctl enable named.service
sudo systemctl start named.service
```

To configure the DNS server, I'm trying YAST2 following [this documentation](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book-opensuse-reference/cha-dns.html):

```
sudo yast2 dns-server
```

I intend to configure `example.com` domain zone with IP address `1.2.3.4`.

#### What I did

I have a DNS zone of *master* type:

[image: Zone: master]

My *NS Records* tab is:

[image: NS Records tab]

My *Records* tab is:

[image: Records tab]

#### Problem

However, saving the configuration runs into a problem:

[image: Problem]

I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which step(s) in https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book-opensuse-reference/cha-dns.html#sec-dns-yast do you not understand?

Comment: @berndbausch Updated =)

Comment: You enter *example.com* in the *Record Key* field, set the *Type* to *A* (since your address is IPv4), and the value to *1.2.3.4*. Creste a NS record for the nameserver's IP address, and I suppose you also need a reverse zone with PTR records for reverse resolution, as documented in the next paragraph.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks. For NS record, what would be the *key* and *value*?

Comment: The name and IP address(es) of your name server(s). In fact, any name should be OK; what's important is the IP address. Are you sure you want to manage a name server without knowing the fundamentals?

Comment: @berndbausch Alright! I'm working on it! Thanks =)

Comment: @berndbausch I completely overhauled the post with my latest try. Maybe I'm missing a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of:

> Warning
>
> Saving the configuration failed. Change the settings?

Got resolved by stopping the `named` service before launching YAST2:

```
sudo systemctl stop named.service
```